# Gigabyte Z77X-UD3H ATX Motherboard No Longer Recognizing USB Devices, Computer Inaccessible

Tags: windows-7, usb, motherboard

around May I built a new computer with the following parts:

- Intel Core i7-3770K Quad-Core processor
- Corsair Vengeance 32GB (4x8GB) DDR3 1600 MHz memory
- MSI Radeon HD 7950 Twin Frozr III 880MHZ 3GB 1250MHZ graphics card
- SeaSonic S12II 520 Bronze 520W power supply
- Plextor 128GB SSD M5S 2.5 SATA
- Western Digital Caviar Black 1TB hard drive
- Gigabyte Z77X-UD3H ATX motherboard

I had an issue with the motherboard which caused the computer to freeze randomly on occasion, requiring a reboot. I posted about that here:

[Windows 7 64-bit custom PC freezing randomly every few days](https://superuser.com/questions/646007/windows-7-64-bit-custom-pc-freezing-randomly-every-few-days)

By turning the "Legacy USB Support" option off in the BIOS, I managed to stop the problem for about a month.  Tonight, however, it happened again, and this time my USB keyboard and mouse are still unresponsive, even after a reboot.  Because of this, I have no method of accessing Windows, and attempting to enter the BIOS results in a blank menu with an unresponsive cursor in the center.  The keyboard responds just long enough to allow me to access this menu before Windows starts, but does nothing afterwards.

I feel like the best option is to completely replace the motherboard, since it seems to be at fault.  Is there a reliable method of accomplishing this while being unable to access the PC, without losing any data?  Will I have to replace it with an identical model?  Any insight into this matter would be appreciated.

EDIT: 11/21/13: After removing the motherboard's battery and unplugging the computer for about 10 minutes, I've managed to regain access to the PC with all USB slots fully functional, although I'm still concerned about this happening again.

Comment: Do you use `Intel Rapid Storage` (RAID or SSD cache)? If not and you'll migrate to intel chipset it sould be ok. Windows activation will not be valid, then it depends on your licence. Is that pc overclocked?

Comment: I think I remember seeing Intel Rapid Storage software on my PC, although I'm not sure if I was using it.  Also,  I have never attempted overclocking that PC.

Comment: **Unless you delete the data on your storage device you cannot lose data.**  So don't delete or modify the data.  If you cannot enter BIOS then the data on your storage device should not be touched.